# Row editing in p:datatable not sending new values to the bean

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use the feature of prime faces which allows user to edit the row data in the table itself.I have followed this link to achieve it:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf

When I say edit user the new values which are entered are not sent to the bean.It still shows the old values only.

My code in JSF:

```
             <p:dataTable value="#{mybean.userList}"
                             var="item"
                             id="dataTab"
                             widgetVar="usersTable"
                             tableStyleClass="data"  paginator="true" rows="5"  
                             filteredValue="#{userController.filteredUsers}"
                             editable="true"
                             rowKey="#{item}"
                             >
                    <p:ajax event="rowEdit"   listener="#{mybean.onEdit}" update=":userForm:growl" />  
                    <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{mybean.onCancel}" update=":userForm:growl" /> 
                    <f:facet name="header">
                    <p:outputPanel>  
                         <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
                         <p:inputText id="globalFilter"     onkeyup="('usersTable').filter()"   style="width:150px" />  
                    </p:outputPanel>     
                    </f:facet>


                    <p:column sortBy="#{item.firstName}" filterBy="#{item.firstName}" 
                              filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                         <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="First Name" />  
                        </f:facet>
                             <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText  value="#{item.firstName}" />
                             </f:facet>
                             <f:facet name="input">  
            <p:inputText value="#{item.firstName}" style="width:100%"/>  
        </f:facet>  
                          </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column  sortBy="#{item.lastName}" filterBy="#{item.lastName}" filterMatchMode="startsWith">
                        <p:cellEditor> 
                        <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Last Name" />  
                        </f:facet>

                    <p:column headerText="Update" style="width:6%">  
                     <p:rowEditor />  
                    </p:column>    




                                        </p:dataTable>
```

My method in the bean:

```
public String onEdit(RowEditEvent event)
    {
User user=(User)event.getObject());
      user.getFirstName();
}
```

When I say that I get the old value of the user's first name but not the new value.So could you let me know what I am missing here.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the scope of your bean?, It should be at lease `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: I think that your scope is wrong. Please, provide more information

Comment: I am using ViewScoped for my bean..

Comment: I suppose your table is wrapped in a `h:form`... do you mean `event.getObject()` returns your old user?

Comment: Yes the table is put in a h:form.event.getObject() returns the value previos value but not the updated value.Wrapping the table in h:form is the problem in this case?

Comment: Could anyone help me out on this..thanks for the help.

Comment: can you use unique ntity property for rowkey like item.id .

Comment: Is the new value being posted in the request (use firebug or chrome network panel)? Is your method being called (do you have any breakpoint in it)?